# What should we do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I saw this question and realized that there is more to this than a LOL moment.

[Fat, white American Buddha Maitreya the Christ](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/fat-white-american-buddha-maitreya-the-christ)

---

As a Buddhist community we can easily see what the point of this person (the imposer) is. And it is no opinion based statement to call this man a lair as we all know that this has nothing to back it's claims and as to any school of Buddhism this is a lie.

---

So my questions are.....

Shouldn't we edit the question more appropriately and answer it with some seriousness as this person seems to be harming two religions at the same time?

Shouldn't we reach out as a community against this butchering of Buddhism in other places like social media (We can easily link our point of views from all schools of Buddhism with the help of our friends here)?

---

If you think i'm wrong for saying this i would like to remind you of that moment when a monk said "We are free from that great sage,now we can do whatever we want" while Lord Buddha was living the last moments of his great life.The other monks did not stood by, they gathered and had the first Buddhist council (Dharma sangayana) to counter the corrupting factors of any kind.

What i see is an equal event where vigilance is needed. There is no debate over what this imposer needs. What we have here is not an occasion to laugh but a chance to show the world who Buddhists are and what Buddhism & teachings of Buddhism really are.

---

If someone want to talk about freedom of speech here and say that it is OK to let this guy expand his little cult i like to propose that person read this.

[**The reason for the first Buddhist council**](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/2_32lbud.htm)

---

I would like to invite our friends here to use their contacts on social media & be vigilant to fight these kinds of cults that has formed. Laugh at this and just chill out if you want but before you do that i would like to point out that millions of innocent Muslims are at a threat as of now in almost every continent because they failed to denounce the little cults that formed claiming to be Islam's, look at what those cults have done now. Their brutality has taken world to a such a misunderstanding in which every Muslim has become a person of interest for the society.

We ignore this guy today but tomorrow another one or two will appear, who knows what these guys are preaching.

Finally what i have to say as a descendant of Sinhalese,we fought for centuries to protect the teaching, everyone from indians to chinese to english to Portuguese wanted to capture my country and destroy the religion if my ancestors said LOL and moved on the world would not have tipitaka today

So if you claim to be a Buddhist,put your money where your mouth is and fight for what you stand for because today the fight is not with blood and sword it is with a functioning mind that sees.

Comment: I respect your sentiments. As a programmer, there are standards (so many of them, yes) for how to code. As Buddhists, there needs to be a standard (one, please) for who can be disqualified as a Buddhist. You can't just call yourself anything you want. I made this point before and was told I was making the "no true Scotsman" argument. Yet, there is a truth in here to be defended.

Comment: Good points, But there is no need for us to define who a Buddhist is because Lord Buddha gave the measures for us to do it. As we already have a solid idea of who a  real Buddhist is there is nothing to hold us back from denouncing what is not Buddhism. And this kind of action is not a form of extremism because it happened many times  in the Buddhist history, Those incidents are called "Buddhist councils". These events occurred to save the teaching from imposers. And all of these events were done by the Great Arahants.

Answer (score 3):

> it is no opinion based statement to call this man a lair as we all know

I'm not really keen on reading (nor on people posting) "rants", on that or any other topics: i.e., firmly-held, fixed opinions which are disguised as questions.

> There is no debate over what this imposer needs.

Perhaps that means that there's no useful question to be asked.

> What we have here is not an occasion to laugh but a chance to show the world who Buddhists are and what Buddhism & teachings of Buddhism really are.

Perhaps we should do that with Q+A about "what Buddhism & teachings of Buddhism really are".

If you think that this person isn't Buddhist, maybe for that reason it becomes off-topic on the site.

See also previous topics, [What can be done about fake monks?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7222/254) and [Real Monk vs Fake Monk](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10946/254).

I don't much want to use the site as a platform for dismissing people who we think aren't sufficiently orthodox/Buddhist.

Some comments like that exist elsewhere on the internet already, and there's no need for such "discussion" on this site. If you created a new topic for everyone you reckon has dubious lineage, doctrine, or morals, that would be a more-or-less endless supply of [flamebait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaming_(Internet)#Flame_trolling).

Comment: It is a fine point that you make and there is no doubt about it but can we address these kind of issues with decency. We have always  been thought provoking can we try explaining this so we can be a source of guidance to people who might misunderstand this as Buddhism?

Comment: I think communities like this can be guardians for the correct path, if we blindly look away when Buddhism itself is edited to fit personal agendas soon services like Buddhism SE will be irrelevant because no one will know what Buddhism  really is.

Comment: There is a story in my country called "The pot of seven beggars". Long story short it goes like this....    one day seven beggars came to one place and started to cook but everyone pretended to put rice in the pot but everyone did not thinking others will and no one will notice their rice missing. In the end cooking was done and they went to eat and saw that there was nothing to eat. ........   This is what happens when people say this is not our issue someone else will take care of it.

Comment: There is also another saying-A sword that does not see war is only good to cut vegetables.If people only come here to show how genius they are to the new guys and hide their tails between their legs and talk nonsense when a real issue in real world comes to existence that only goes on to show who they really are. What i see with some people here is that like those geeks who play battlefield all day long they come here to satisfy their god complex over the fellow minions and soon as they see something off their comfort zone the technicalities  come out with few links to the site policies.